# Is there a way to resolve an issue with nginx status Active: inactive (dead) problem in CENTOS

Tags: nginx

This is what it brings when you check nginx status

```
[root@ttproxyapp conf.d]# service nginx status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - nginx - high performance web server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Comment: Have you tried to start the service? `service nginx start`? is there any error? Can you run `nginx -t`? whats the ouput of it?

Comment: When I run the said commands I get the following output @TimoStark

Comment: [root@ttproxyapp run]# nginx -s reload
Enter PEM pass phrase:
nginx: [error] open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
[root@ttproxyapp run]# nginx -t
Enter PEM pass phrase:
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Answer (score 17):

```
sudo systemctl stop apache2
sudo systemctl start nginx
```

should work since looks like the port is in use (with apache probably)

Answer (score 2):

It realy looks like your NGINX ins't running. `nginx -s reload` is just working if there is a running instance and therfore a PID-file.

Please check the result of the following command.

```
[root@localhost conf.d]# sudo ps -elf | grep nginx
```

Should be something like

```
1 S root      88262      1  0  80   0 - 13143 sigsus 23:47 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
5 S nginx     88263  88262  0  80   0 - 13257 ep_pol 23:47 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
0 R root      88265  69227  0  80   0 - 28178 -      23:47 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

You need at least! the master process and the worker process! If there is no process start your instance by typing

`sudo /bin/systemctl start nginx.service` OR `sudo service nginx start`

Check your processlist after running the command.

After you have started the NGINX service there should be PID-file located at 
`/var/run/nginx.pid` and `sudo systemctl status nginx.service` should printout something like

```
[root@localhost conf.d]# systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - NGINX Plus - high performance web server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-03-14 23:47:13 EDT; 5min ago
     Docs: https://www.nginx.com/resources/
  Process: 88232 ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 88260 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 88251 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/nginx-plus/check-subscription (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 88262 (nginx)
    Tasks: 2
   Memory: 1.7M
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─88262 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
           └─88263 nginx: worker process

Mar 14 23:47:13 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting NGINX Plus - high performance web server...
Mar 14 23:47:13 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Can't open PID file /var/run/nginx.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Mar 14 23:47:13 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started NGINX Plus - high performance web server.
```

I am running NGINX Plus but it doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 2):

there is maybe an apache server running. you must stop that apache server order run the Nginx server.

sudo systemctl stop apache2

sudo systemctl start nginx